# Node.js outputs to console fine but not through server response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is my test node.js code using express and mathjs packages. The is just adding two numbers received from the url. I tried "parseInt", "Number" both with no luck in getting the output from resp.send on the localhost:3000. The server page just shows a blank page.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
var express = require('express');
var mathjs = require('mathjs');

var app = express();
var math = mathjs();

app.get('/app/arithmetic/range/:value1,:value2', function(req, resp) {
    var val1 = Number(req.params.value1);
    var val2 = Number(req.params.value2);
    var sum = math.add(val1,val2);
    console.log(sum);
    resp.send(sum);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**UPDATE:** Issue resolved. I was trying to output an integer, which for some reason express doesn't like. so I made the *resp.send(sum);* to *resp.send(sum.toString());* and it worked. Alternative way could be *resp.send(''+sum);*

Comment: what does `req.params` gives you?

Comment: Found the problem, "The first argument must be a string or buffer". If I resp.send(''+sum); it works fine, but it looks like a mere workaround to me :/ Does that mean I can't print integers alone?

Comment: `resp.send({"sum":sum})`, maybe?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix req.params gives nothing, but req.params.value1 and req.params.value2 gives the same integers I entered in the URL.

Comment: @GeoPhoenix No I'm not looking to include any string just the sum integer. And what does the curly braces do in resp.send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is passing just a number in the [`resp.send`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.send). Quoting from the docs,

> #### res.send([body|status], [body])
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> when a Number is given without any of the previously mentioned bodies, then a response body string is assigned for you.

So, when you simply pass a number, express framework assumes that as HTTP status code and returns it with the predefined response body (for the known response codes). To confirm this, try returning 404 from your application. By default, it would say `Not Found`.

To fix this, you need to convert the number to string, like this

```
resp.send((1).toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, made the change but the original issue's still there.